# C# Merging 2 dictionaries and adding values between them

Tags: c#, dictionary

I am learning C# and needed to merge two dictionaries so I could add values found in both.

The first dictionary is payePlusNssf that holds a value for each key (key represents employee ID). So far I have employees 1,2,3,4 and 5

```
Dictionary<int, decimal> payePlusNssf = new Dictionary<int, decimal>();

paye.ToList().ForEach(x =>
{
    var deductNSSF = x.Value + nssfAmount;

    payePlusNssf.Add(x.Key, deductNSSF);
});
```

The 2nd dictionary is nhifRatesDictionary that holds rates to be added to each value per employee in the first dictionary.

```
Dictionary<int, IEnumerable<NHIFRates>> nhifRatesDictionary =
   new Dictionary<int, IEnumerable<NHIFRates>>();

basicPayDictionary.ToList().ForEach(x =>
{
    List<NHIFRates> nhifValueList = new List<NHIFRates>();

    // Using Employee basic pay
    decimal basicPay = x.Value;

    bool foundflag = false;

    foreach (var item in nhifBracketList)
    {
        if (basicPay >= item.Min && basicPay <= item.Max)
        {
            nhifValueList.Add(new NHIFRates { Rate = item.Rate });

            foundflag = true;
            break;
        }                       
    }

    if (!foundflag)
    {
        nhifValueList.Add(new NHIFRates { Rate = 0m });
    }

    nhifRatesDictionary.Add(x.Key, nhifValueList);
});

struct NHIFRates
{
    public decimal Rate { get; set; }
}
```

In summary I need this after merging and adding:

```
Dict 1          Dict 2          Result Dict 3
key  value      key  rate       key  value
1     500       1     80        1    580
2    1000       2     100       2   1100
3    2000       3     220       3   2220
4     800       4     300       4   1100
5    1000       5     100       5   1100
```

How do I achieve this? I have looked at past similar problems on this site but have not been very helpful to me.

Comment: You mean you want to add the value from the first dictionary and all the rates in the second dictionary for each employee? Is it guaranteed that every employee from the first dictionary is in the second one too?

Comment: I must need caffine. Im a little confused by your code. Why are you using dictionaries for this? OK, so, your second dictionary, could have been simplified to a Dictionary<int,decimal>, if you worked with that, foreach the first dictionary, lookup value if in second, do the job, add item to the new dictionary,else just add it as no change required

Comment: @svick Every employee in the 1st dictionary will be in the second on too, ie, matching perfectly. I need to add each rate calculated in dict2 to be added to the respective value in dict1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not tested but try:

```
payePlusNssf.ToDictionary(
            v => v.Key, 
            v => v.Value + nhifRatesDictionary[v.Key].Sum(nhifr => nhifr.Rate)
                         );
```

This assumes that since the value of `nhifRatesDictionary` is IEnumreable you want to sum over all the values in the enumerable. This should also work if the IEnumerable is empty. If you know that there is exactly one value for each key then you can use:

```
payePlusNssf.ToDictionary(
            v => v.Key, 
            v => v.Value + nhifRatesDictionary[v.Key].Single(nhifr => nhifr.Rate)
                         );
```

Answer (score 1):

What about a simple for cycle?

```
Dictionary<int,decimal> d3 = new Dictionary<int,decimal>();
for (int i = 1,i<=payePlusNssf.Count,i++)
{
    d3.Add (i,payePlusNssf[i]+((nhifRatesDictionary[i])[0]).Rate);
}
```

If the ID numbers are not guranteed to be this simple you can use

```
foreach (var x in payePlusNssf)
{
    d3.Add(x.Key,x.Value+ ((nhifRatesDictionary[x.Key])[0]).Rate);
}
```

Or do it completely differently, do not keep three separate dictionaries that are guaranteed to have the same keys and create an employee class like

```
class Employee
{
    public decimal payePlusNssf;
    public decimal nhifRate;
    public decimal Sum
    {
        get { return payePlusNssf + nhifRate ;}
    }
}
```

and have one Dictionary with everything - saves you problems with keeping the dictionaries all updated.

Comment: The value of `nhifRatesDictionary` is an `IEnumerable<NHIFRates>` there is no direct `Rate` property to the value.

Comment: The key in the dictionary is an id. You can't expect them to be continuous. And if they weren't, your code wouldn't work.

Comment: @svick That's where the foreach version comes.

Comment: @Variant My bad. But it seems to me that there will always be exactly one item in it, which makes all the IEnumerable useless. I updated it.